# Ubuntu 18.04 "Advanced Installation" official guide for RAID 1 installation appears broken for UEFI installation

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, raid1, uefi

I had no issues earlier with RAID 1 setup on Ubuntu 16.04. However, on 18.04 it has been a struggle. I finally located this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html).

I followed the guideline to the dot.  However, I am unable to set the Bootable flag  (Step 8). I can only do so if I select partition type to be "EFI system partition". If I do so, I get problems in the next step.

The steps are repeated here from the instructions:

```
1. Select Manual as the partition method.

2. Select the first hard drive, and agree to "Create a new empty
partition table on this device?".
Repeat this step for each drive you wish to be part of the RAID
array.

3. Select the "FREE SPACE" on the first drive then select "Create a new
partition".

4. Next, select the Size of the partition. This partition will be the
swap partition, and a general rule for swap size is twice that of
RAM. Enter the partition size, then choose Primary, then Beginning.

 A swap partition size of twice the available RAM capacity may not
 always be desirable, especially on systems with large amounts of
 RAM. Calculating the swap partition size for servers is highly
 dependent on how the system is going to be used.

5. Select the "Use as:" line at the top. By default this is "Ext4
journaling file system", change that to "physical volume for RAID"
then "Done setting up partition".

6.  For the / partition once again select "Free Space" on the first
drive then "Create a new partition".

7.  Use the rest of the free space on the drive and choose Continue,
then Primary.

8.  As with the swap partition, select the "Use as:" line at the top,
changing it to "physical volume for RAID". Also select the "Bootable
flag:" line to change the value to "on". Then choose "Done setting
up partition".

9.  Repeat steps three through eight for the other disk and partitions.
```

Comment: Well, that's clearly an error. The "bootable flag" is only used on old MSDOS partitions and is not used for EFI booting.